# How can I use DotNetNuke's built-in Sessions and Cookies for my own login module?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session-cookies, dotnetnuke

Does anyone have an example of how to use DNN's built-in functionality for a custom Login Module which can store the User Login with a Session and Cookie?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController`.
It has all kinds of methods for user handling. For login it has

```
void UserLogin(int portalId, UserInfo user, string portalName, string ip, bool createPersistentCookie);
UserInfo UserLogin(int portalId, string username, string password, string verificationCode, string portalName, string ip, ref UserLoginStatus loginStatus, bool createPersistentCookie);
```

Comment: Awesome, so I can use this for a Remember Me checkbox on DNN?

Comment: Yes, with a `createPersistentCookie`